# Need to do a bulk update to a subset of a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to bulk update a list of records resulting from the query:

```
select * 
from Subscribers S with (nolock)
where S.COUNTRY_CD is not null and S.REGION is null
```

So, running the above query gives me ONLY the records that I need to update.

Then, as I alluded to, I need to perform an update to **ONLY** update these records. I'm not a SQL whiz by any means. How can I basically iterate through the result set I get above and perform an update on each of these records?

Comment: You can apply a where clause to an update statement - UPDATE subscribers SET SomeField = 'Some Value' WHERE Country_CD IS NOT NULL AND Region IS NULL`

Comment: @GarethD I appreciate it, thanks... it's been awhile since I've done any SQL.

Comment: Be careful with (nolock).  While it's true that no locks will be issued it will also read uncommitted data which can be quite dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update has quite flexible syntax in SQL Server. When you have a SELECT of the form

```
SELECT Cols
FROM T
JOIN ...
WHERE Condition
```

and want to make it into an UPDATE you mechanically transform it to this:

```
UPDATE T
SET ...
FROM T
JOIN ...
WHERE Condition
```

Note, that I just pasted the last three lines without modification. You should now be able to adapt your query to be a set-based update.